# How to change logging configuration from within my own code, without touching the code in the (upstream) module?

Tags: python, oop, logging, module

This code demonstrates how to log stuff from inside my class. It is a simplified version of what I find in a module called [mptools](https://github.com/PamelaM/mptools/tree/master/mptools). Now I want to use this kind of logging in my project, together with the mptools module. How can I keep the changes which make logging to syslog work local to my own code, and outside the module?

The code in between the `#=======` marks is inside the module, the rest is in my own code.

```
#=======
# module code here
import functools
import sys
import logging
from logging import config
#=======
# my own code here
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(module)s P%(process)d T%(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'stdout': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'sys-logger6': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            "address": ["127.0.0.1", 514],
            'facility': "local6",
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'my-logger': {
            'handlers': ['sys-logger6', 'stdout'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

config.dictConfig(LOGGING)

my_logger = logging.getLogger('my-logger')

#=======
# module code here
def _logger(level, msg, exc_info=None):
    my_logger.log(level, f'{msg}', exc_info=exc_info)
    # the original code in the module uses logging.log() here.


class ContextManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = functools.partial(_logger, "init")

    def __enter__(self):
        self.log(logging.ERROR, f"entering...")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type:
            self.log(logging.ERROR, f"Exception: {exc_val}", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb))
        else:
            self.log(logging.DEBUG, f"no exception, peaceful end")
#=======
# my own code here

def main():
    with ContextManager() as ctx:
        ctx.log(logging.INFO, f"running in main")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  # this is in the example code of the module, most likely to set the global log level
    main()
```

Please also make suggestions on how to adapt the title of this question so the usefulness for others interested in code-extraction or code-seperation increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the module uses `logging.log()` it's sending logs directly to the root logger. It's not best practice for modules to do that, but it can be worked around. Basically you just have to add your handlers to the root logger instead of creating your own named logger.

```py
import logging

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'sys-logger6': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            "address": ["127.0.0.1", 514],
            'facility': "local6",
        },
    },
    'root': {
            'handlers': ['sys-logger6'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)

logging.log(logging.INFO, "this log will be sent to syslog")
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you speak a little about the module situation, too? For example, will this (the LOGGING= ... and the logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)) in my code affect the logging in the mptools module? If not, how can I achieve that?

Comment: It doesn't change what the module logs and to what logger, that can't be changed. But this will affect how those logs are handled. So this will send all logs from that module to the syslog. Basically you can't do anything about the root logger, but you have full control over handlers, so you can't change what logs are created, but you have control over what happens to them.

Comment: i will implement this and write my results here!